# Image with parameters renders with reddish overlay

Tags: image, grid, overlay, umbraco

I have an Umbraco 10 site where I use a grid and insert images into the grid. The images are rendering with parameters eg.

```
/media/tavndatn/d58553_5475de341c9344b7ad65acb40ac06b5a_mv2.jpg?rmode=max&width=136&height=143
```

The problem is that without parameters the image looks ok, however with the parameters it renders with a red overlay. I have no idea why and where it comes from.

Even when displaying the image link directly in the browser - it always renders with the red overlay.

Any suggestions?

Why the images are rendering with parameters in the first place and how to remove the overlay? There doesn't seem to be any particular style assigned to the images, no background, no other attributes.

[image]

[image]

The images display ok here as you can see above - first have the parameters and the second does not have any.
It seems to affect jpg images for now, gif & png display ok.

Comment: You would need to add links to the actual images on the site - the two examples above are outside of the Umbraco installation, so aren't affected by the parameters as ImageSharp is not in play.  Consider also reporting this on the ImageSharp issue tracker here: https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have upgraded to Umbraco 10.2.0 and the problem has gone. Apparently there was issue with Image Sharp in version 10.0.0